# Which programming languages have a regular grammar?

Tags: programming-languages, compiler-theory, regular-language

I'm curious about which (if any) real-world programming languages have a regular grammar (i.e. the set of all syntactically correct programs is regular).

See also this question: [What programming languages are context-free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898489/what-programming-languages-are-context-free).

Comment: As a practical matter, none of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) and [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) and similars are certainly regular.

On the other side, any language that supports (parens) is not regular, as the automaton recognizing it would need a stack. And I don't really know many languages without (){}[] support that would do anything more than assembly.

Only real-worldy example that comes to mind and probably is regular is [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: FYI your comment on (parens) is incorrect. Old Fortran had parens .. but with a limit of 3 deep.

Comment: What is the relevance of regular languages in modern computing? Intuitively I would imagine that to implement something on circuits it would need to be a regular language, and machine code syntax seems like it would be regular. Is there any time in software that regular languages are useful? It seems I hardly ever use strict regular languages -- PCRE has "regular expression" in its name but isn't even strictly regular if I understand correctly.

Comment: Brainfuck is not a regular language, as it allows nested loops where `[` marks the beginning of a loop and `]` marks the end. As these must match, brainfuck is not regular.

Comment: @Palle Depending on the implementation, brainfuck can be regular or not. You parse them as `while{}` statements or as push `[` and pop+jmp/ret `]` instructions. Technically, there is no need for the bracket count to match.

Comment: @KeksArmee You are mixing up translation with actual parsing. Of course you can translate brainfuck to C using just simple replacement operations but to actually parse correct brainfuck, you need a parser that can handle at least context free grammars. You cannot express the set of all syntactically correct brainfuck programs using a regular grammar.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES. There are certainly programming languages with regular grammar!

The A=B programming language is a one instruction esolang which is regular.

https://esolangs.org/wiki/A%3DB

Here is the regular expression that matches any such language:

```
((\(once\))?([^=()]+|\(start\)[^=()]+|\(end\)[^=()]+)=([^=()]*|\(start\)[^=()]*|\(end\)[^=()]*|\(return\)[^=()]*))*
```

In fact, it is possible to describe a Turing machine using regular language.
Let the states of the Turing machine be called `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, etc, where `a` is the initial state. we can describe a Turing machine as follows, assuming the tape only contains `0`, `1` and `2`, where `0` is the blank symbol:

```
([012]a+=[012][lr]a+)*
```