# RegEx to find whole class in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have some problem with finding whole class text using RegEx in C#. I need whole structure, including "public class ..." to last parenthesis, because it will be compiled as dynamic code (using CSharpCodeProvider object).

Here is sample code of my class:

```
    [Worker("Structure")]
    public class DataSourceStructure
    {
        DataSet mainData = new DataSet();
        DataTable worker = new DataTable("Worker");
        DataTable year = new DataTable("Year");

        public DataSet MainSource 
        {       
           get 
           {
            worker.Columns.Add("Name");
            worker.Columns.Add("MonthSallary");
            worker.Columns.Add("DateOfBirth");
            worker.Columns.Add("WorkDescription");
            worker.Columns.Add("Sex");
            worker.Columns.Add("Worker_Id", typeof(int));

            year.Columns.Add("YearOfEmployment");
            year.Columns.Add("Worker_Id", typeof(int));

            mainData.Tables.Add(worker);
            mainData.Tables.Add(year);

            DataRelation rel = new DataRelation("Worker_Year", mainData.Tables["Worker"].Columns["Worker_Id"], mainData.Tables["Year"].Columns["Worker_Id"], true);

            mainData.Relations.Add(rel);

            return mainData;
           }
           set 
           { 
            mainData = value; 
           } 
       }
   }
```

I tried some ways described on StackOverflow (for example: [Using RegEx to balance match parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898310/using-regex-to-balance-match-parenthesis)), but it doesn't work for me... or I don't know how to rebuild it correctly. ;/

Thanks in advance for every help.

Comment: You do have one class per file?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no - there are many classes and attributes definitions.

Comment: `(public class .*})\s+\b\w+\b class` using singleLine option ?

Comment: I think that this could easily fall over into the category of items where you have to abandon regex and use a *parser*. Especially once you realise that just balancing braces isn't sufficient when strings and comments are allowed to contain unmatched braces.

Comment: Thomas - Your pattern works (no errors) but it can't be used, because there are many classes and attributes definitions so I get one match consists of whole text in file. ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression will not always work for your use-case. This is because C# grammar is quite complex ([context-free with some context specific rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096512/802203https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096512/802203)) and a regular expression can only express/parse [regular grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammarhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar).

Consider using [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) instead. [Here](http://www.filipekberg.se/2011/10/20/using-roslyn-to-parse-c-code-files/) is a tutorial and a simple snippet of code to get you started.

```
var code = new StreamReader("path/to/cs/file/here").ReadToEnd();
var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(code);
var classes = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What happens if there is another class or something else after the class closing braces?

Comment: ananthonline - thank You very much for answer, but we can't use any externall DLLs to achieve this task.

Comment: The Roslyn parser is used in the C# compiler. It is robust enough to handle all of those conditions and more.

Comment: Yes, You're right. I will talk to my manager and try to convince him to Roslyn. Thank You and I accept Your solution.