# Is C# a regular language?

Tags: c#, regular-language

I'm writing some static analysis tools and have been trying to avoid doing full-on compilation style string parsing, and that brought me to this question.

Is C# a regular language?

Why or why not?

Comment: Just in case you've missed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/ - good read... And it is for much simple language by the way.

Comment: or have a look at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, that's a classic answer and an entertaining one, but it doesn't answer this question, nor does it touch upon the reasons for this answer.

Comment: @ThomSmith serious part actually contains main part of the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/477420 (context free > regular) + some basic search (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428934/is-c-sharp-considered-a-context-free-language or rare common sense) will give the real answer ... Can't close as duplicate of both so...

Comment: Use Roslyn if you need a C# parser and semantic analyzer. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Incidentally, C# is not even a *decidable* language; it was recently proved that languages with nominal subtyping and contravariant interfaces are not decidable.  Even leaving aside that, overload resolution is at least NP-HARD.

Comment: C# *type checking* is not decidable. But parsing is. C# isn't Perl, after all. Also, are you referring to the result by Kennedy & Pierce, or something more recent?

Comment: @ThomSmith: A C# program that does not type check is not a legal C# program. If the question is *is the language C# without type checking* decidable, yes it is, but that is not C#. The question is about C#.

Comment: @ThomSmith: The paper you're referring to conjectures that it is undecidable but does not prove it; a recent paper proves it.  Funnily enough, the author of that paper learned of the conjecture from one of my SO answers, which I find quite amusing!  The paper is "Java Generics Are Turing Complete" by Radu Grigoire.

Comment: Now, if you are interested in just C# as she is parsed, fun fact: the language can in theory require arbitrary far look-ahead to parse correctly, due to some ambiguities introduced by generics. In practice these scenarios don't arise often.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635/what-static-analysis-tools-are-available-for-c

Answer (score 6):

No. C# is not a regular language. C# lets you nest parentheses arbitrarily deep, and a regular language cannot recognize correct bracket matching. This, by itself, means that C# is not regular.

Comment: thanks!  simple answer to a simple question :)