# Xcode 6 / 7 Project, generate Class Diagram (UML)

Tags: xcode, class, uml, diagram

So lately I joined a company which has been developing on their core business application for several years, which has seen multiple developers over the past years. As in many projects there has been a huge lack of documenting the source code.

My job is to organise the code, find dead code, make stuff more efficient etc.
Because this project is a 80+ class project I would really appreciate a class diagram to give me some overview of the project.

When I do a search most anwsers date back to '11 or '14 which suggest to use OmniGraffle. Well I do have OmniGraffle installed on my macBook but I need to have the Pro version to create diagrams from Xcode projects.

Is there any WORKING tool out there on the WWW that could help me out, or maybe some one with a OmniGraffle PRO license to confirm that this functionality is working? In that case I will advise the company to buy a pro license.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UML class diagrams for Xcode (swift programming)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186136/uml-class-diagrams-for-xcode-swift-programming)

Comment: XCode is an IDE. But UML is REed for Code. Most likely this will now be Swift (see above) but for Obj-C it's the same answer.

Comment: OmniGraffle offers RE for Obj-C to create UML. But not for Swift. See e.g. http://forums.omnigroup.com/showthread.php?t=24129

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys.
I did find these articles myself but find them a little low on information.